# Import WooCoomerce site Transaction into Quickbook Desktop 2015 via PHP and web connector

Tags: wordpress, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I am creating wordpress woocommerce site which is almost ready , now what i want is, I want to import all my customers , users, orders , products and transactions etc. into my quickbook desktop.

From documentation, i have already reached to a point where i can simple get customers from site to QB Desktop using the samples files provided here [QB PHP SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SIdY.png).

My basic question is, how i will get sales orders , purchase order etc. things which are required in QBDesktop but not available in my site.

I have also created all tables from here [QB Transaction tables][2] , now point is how to insert data inside these tables. If suppose i use wordpress webhooks to enter some information into these tables, so now what about the fields unknown to me also this file name has `import` database. so what does that mean Importing from site to QBWC or Importing from QBDesktop to QBWC.

The docs seems confusing for me , my ultimate aim is to Move things from my site into QBDesktop , after this i will try reverse process.

Updated:
I have made changes inside your sdk `docs/example_app_web_connector` .
This is `qbwc.php` :

```
<?php

    /**
     * Example Web Connector application
     * 
     * This is a very simple application that allows someone to enter a customer 
     * name into a web form, and then adds the customer to QuickBooks.
     * 
     * @author Keith Palmer <keith@consolibyte.com>
     * 
     * @package QuickBooks
     * @subpackage Documentation
     */

    /**
     * Require some configuration stuff
     */ 
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php';

    /**
     * Require some callback functions
     */ 
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/functions.php';

    // Map QuickBooks actions to handler functions
    $map = array(
        QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER => array( '_quickbooks_customer_add_request', '_quickbooks_customer_add_response' ),
        QUICKBOOKS_ADD_ITEM => array( '_quickbooks_item_add_request', '_quickbooks_item_add_response' ),
        QUICKBOOKS_ADD_ESTIMATE =>array( '_quickbooks_estimate_add_request', '_quickbooks_estimate_add_response' ),
        QUICKBOOKS_ADD_SALESORDER => array( '_quickbooks_salesorder_add_request', '_quickbooks_salesorder_add_response' ),
        QUICKBOOKS_ADD_SALESRECEIPT => array( '_quickbooks_salesreceipt_add_request', '_quickbooks_salesreceipt_add_response' ),
        QUICKBOOKS_ADD_INVOICE => array( '_quickbooks_invoice_add_request', '_quickbooks_invoice_add_response' ),
        QUICKBOOKS_ADD_PURCHASEORDER => array( '_quickbooks_purchaseorder_add_request', '_quickbooks_purchaseorder_add_response' ),
        );

    // This is entirely optional, use it to trigger actions when an error is returned by QuickBooks
    $errmap = array(
        '*' => '_quickbooks_error_catchall',                // Using a key value of '*' will catch any errors which were not caught by another error handler
        );

    // An array of callback hooks
    $hooks = array(
        );

    // Logging level
    $log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_DEVELOP;        // Use this level until you're sure everything works!!!

    // What SOAP server you're using 
    $soapserver = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_BUILTIN;        // A pure-PHP SOAP server (no PHP ext/soap extension required, also makes debugging easier)

    $soap_options = array(      // See http://www.php.net/soap
        );

    $handler_options = array(
        'deny_concurrent_logins' => false, 
        'deny_reallyfast_logins' => false, 
        );      // See the comments in the QuickBooks/Server/Handlers.php file

    $driver_options = array(        // See the comments in the QuickBooks/Driver/<YOUR DRIVER HERE>.php file ( i.e. 'Mysql.php', etc. )
        );

    $callback_options = array(
        );

    // Create a new server and tell it to handle the requests
    // __construct($dsn_or_conn, $map, $errmap = array(), $hooks = array(), $log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_NORMAL, $soap = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_PHP, $wsdl = QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options = array(), $handler_options = array(), $driver_options = array(), $callback_options = array()
    $Server = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server($dsn, $map, $errmap, $hooks, $log_level, $soapserver, QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options, $handler_options, $driver_options, $callback_options);
    $response = $Server->handle(true, true);
    ?>
```

And this is my `functions.php` :

```
<?php

    /**
     * Example Web Connector application
     * 
     * This is a very simple application that allows someone to enter a customer 
     * name into a web form, and then adds the customer to QuickBooks.
     * 
     * @author Keith Palmer <keith@consolibyte.com>
     * 
     * @package QuickBooks
     * @subpackage Documentation
     */

    /**
     * Generate a qbXML response to add a particular customer to QuickBooks
     */
    function _quickbooks_customer_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
    {
        // Grab the data from our MySQL database
        $arr = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_customer_table WHERE id = " . (int) $ID));

        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
            <QBXML>
                <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                    <CustomerAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                        <CustomerAdd>
                            <Name>' . $arr['name'] . '</Name>
                            <CompanyName>' . $arr['name'] . '</CompanyName>
                            <FirstName>' . $arr['fname'] . '</FirstName>
                            <LastName>' . $arr['lname'] . '</LastName>
                        </CustomerAdd>
                    </CustomerAddRq>
                </QBXMLMsgsRq>
            </QBXML>';

        return $xml;
    }

    /**
     * Receive a response from QuickBooks 
     */
    function _quickbooks_customer_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
    {   
        mysql_query("
            UPDATE 
                my_customer_table 
            SET 
                quickbooks_listid = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($idents['ListID']) . "', 
                quickbooks_editsequence = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($idents['EditSequence']) . "'
            WHERE 
                id = " . (int) $ID);
    }

    /**
     * Catch and handle an error from QuickBooks
     */
    function _quickbooks_error_catchall($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $xml, $errnum, $errmsg)
    {
        mysql_query("
            UPDATE 
                my_customer_table 
            SET 
                quickbooks_errnum = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($errnum) . "', 
                quickbooks_errmsg = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($errmsg) . "'
            WHERE 
                id = " . (int) $ID);
    }


    /*-------------------------------------------------------new---------------------------------------*/

    /**
     * Generate a qbXML response to add a particular Items to QuickBooks
     */
    function _quickbooks_item_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
    {
        // Grab the data from our MySQL database    
        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
            <QBXML>
                <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                    <ItemInventoryAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                        <ItemInventoryAdd>
                            <Name>Item Name 1</Name>
                            <SalesDesc>your sales description here</SalesDesc>
                            <SalesPrice>85.00</SalesPrice>
                            <IncomeAccountRef>
                                <FullName>Sales</FullName>
                            </IncomeAccountRef>
                            <COGSAccountRef>
                                <FullName>Cost of Goods Sold</FullName>
                            </COGSAccountRef>
                            <AssetAccountRef>
                                <FullName>Inventory Asset</FullName>
                            </AssetAccountRef>
                        </ItemInventoryAdd>
                    </ItemInventoryAddRq>
                </QBXMLMsgsRq>
            </QBXML>';

        return $xml;
    }

    /**
     * Receive a response from QuickBooks 
     */
    function _quickbooks_item_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
    {   

    }

    /**
     * Generate a qbXML response to add a particular Estimate to QuickBooks
     */
    function _quickbooks_estimate_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
    {
        // Grab the data from our MySQL database    
        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
            <QBXML>
                <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                    <EstimateAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                        <EstimateAdd>
                            <CustomerRef>
                                <FullName>Keith Company</FullName>
                            </CustomerRef>
                            <TxnDate>2007-12-14</TxnDate>
                            <RefNumber>9668</RefNumber>
                            <BillAddress>
                                <Addr1>56 Cowles Road</Addr1>
                                <City>Willington</City>
                                <State>CT</State>
                                <PostalCode>06279</PostalCode>
                                <Country>United States</Country>
                            </BillAddress>
                            <EstimateLineAdd>
                                <ItemRef>
                                    <FullName>Item Name 1</FullName>
                                </ItemRef>
                                <Desc>Item 1 Description Goes Here</Desc>
                                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                                <Rate>295</Rate>
                            </EstimateLineAdd>
                            <EstimateLineAdd>
                                <ItemRef>
                                    <FullName>Item Name 2</FullName>
                                </ItemRef>
                                <Desc>Item 2 Description Goes Here</Desc>
                                <Quantity>3</Quantity>
                                <Rate>25</Rate>
                            </EstimateLineAdd>

                        </EstimateAdd>
                    </EstimateAddRq>
                </QBXMLMsgsRq>
            </QBXML>';

        return $xml;
    }

    /**
     * Receive a response from QuickBooks 
     */
    function _quickbooks_estimate_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
    {   

    }



    /** 
     * 
     * @param string $requestID                 You should include this in your qbXML request (it helps with debugging later)
     * @param string $action                    The QuickBooks action being performed (CustomerAdd in this case)
     * @param mixed $ID                         The unique identifier for the record (maybe a customer ID number in your database or something)
     * @param array $extra                      Any extra data you included with the queued item when you queued it up
     * @param string $err                       An error message, assign a value to $err if you want to report an error
     * @param integer $last_action_time         A unix timestamp (seconds) indicating when the last action of this type was dequeued (i.e.: for CustomerAdd, the last time a customer was added, for CustomerQuery, the last time a CustomerQuery ran, etc.)
     * @param integer $last_actionident_time    A unix timestamp (seconds) indicating when the combination of this action and ident was dequeued (i.e.: when the last time a CustomerQuery with ident of get-new-customers was dequeued)
     * @param float $version                    The max qbXML version your QuickBooks version supports
     * @param string $locale                    
     * @return string                           A valid qbXML request
     */
    function _quickbooks_salesreceipt_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
    {
        /*
            <CustomerRef>
                <ListID>80003579-1231522938</ListID>
            </CustomerRef>  
        */

        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
            <QBXML>
                <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                    <SalesReceiptAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                        <SalesReceiptAdd>
                            <CustomerRef>
                                <FullName>Keith Palmer Jr.</FullName>
                            </CustomerRef>
                            <TxnDate>2009-01-09</TxnDate>
                            <RefNumber>16466</RefNumber>
                            <BillAddress>
                                <Addr1>Keith Palmer Jr.</Addr1>
                                <Addr3>134 Stonemill Road</Addr3>
                                <City>Storrs-Mansfield</City>
                                <State>CT</State>
                                <PostalCode>06268</PostalCode>
                                <Country>United States</Country>
                            </BillAddres>
                            <SalesReceiptLineAdd>
                                <ItemRef>
                                    <FullName>Gift Certificate</FullName>
                                </ItemRef>
                                <Desc>$25.00 gift certificate</Desc>
                                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                                <Rate>25.00</Rate>
                                <SalesTaxCodeRef>
                                    <FullName>NON</FullName>
                                </SalesTaxCodeRef>
                            </SalesReceiptLineAdd>
                            <SalesReceiptLineAdd>
                                <ItemRef>
                                    <FullName>Book</FullName>
                                </ItemRef>
                                <Desc>The Hitchhiker\'s Guide to the Galaxy</Desc>
                                <Amount>19.95</Amount>
                                <SalesTaxCodeRef>
                                    <FullName>TAX</FullName>
                                </SalesTaxCodeRef>
                            </SalesReceiptLineAdd>
                        </SalesReceiptAdd>
                    </SalesReceiptAddRq>
                </QBXMLMsgsRq>
            </QBXML>';

        return $xml;
    }

    /**
     * Receive a response from QuickBooks 
     */
    function _quickbooks_salesreceipt_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
    {   

    }

    function _quickbooks_salesorder_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
    {

        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                    <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
                    <QBXML>
                        <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                            <SalesOrderAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                                <SalesOrderAdd>
                                    <CustomerRef>
                                        <FullName>BhagyaMazire</FullName>
                                    </CustomerRef>
                                    <TxnDate>2013-05-23</TxnDate>
                                    <RefNumber>23112628110</RefNumber>
                                    <BillAddress>
                                        <Addr1>Pam  Barker</Addr1>
                                        <Addr2>500 Kirts Boulevard</Addr2>
                                        <Addr3/>
                                        <City>Troy</City>
                                        <State>Mi</State>
                                        <PostalCode>48084</PostalCode>
                                        <Country>US</Country>
                                    </BillAddress>
                                    <ShipAddress>
                                        <Addr1/>
                                        <Addr2>7322 Southwest Freeway </Addr2>
                                        <Addr3>Ste, 170</Addr3>
                                        <City>Houston</City>
                                        <State>TX</State>
                                        <PostalCode>77074</PostalCode>
                                        <Country>US</Country>
                                    </ShipAddress>
                                    <ItemSalesTaxRef>
                                        <FullName>Out of State</FullName>
                                    </ItemSalesTaxRef>
                                    <Memo>Shipping to Pinnacle Senior Care Houston </Memo>
                                    <SalesOrderLineAdd>
                                        <ItemRef>
                                            <FullName>Booklets:CB1-101</FullName>
                                        </ItemRef>
                                        <Desc>CHF</Desc>
                                        <Quantity>15</Quantity>
                                        <Amount>59.25</Amount>
                                    </SalesOrderLineAdd>
                                    <SalesOrderLineAdd>
                                        <ItemRef>
                                            <FullName>Booklets:CB3-101</FullName>
                                        </ItemRef>
                                        <Desc>High Blood Pressure</Desc>
                                        <Quantity>15</Quantity>
                                        <Amount>59.25</Amount>
                                    </SalesOrderLineAdd>
                                    <SalesOrderLineAdd>
                                        <ItemRef>
                                            <FullName>Booklets:DB1-101</FullName>
                                        </ItemRef>
                                        <Desc>Diabetes Type 1 or 2 with Insulin</Desc>
                                        <Quantity>15</Quantity>
                                        <Amount>59.25</Amount>
                                    </SalesOrderLineAdd>
                                    <SalesOrderLineAdd>
                                        <ItemRef>
                                            <FullName>Booklets:DB2-101</FullName>
                                        </ItemRef>
                                        <Desc>Diabetes Type 1 or 2 w/o Insulin</Desc>
                                        <Quantity>15</Quantity>
                                        <Amount>59.25</Amount>
                                    </SalesOrderLineAdd>
                                </SalesOrderAdd>
                            </SalesOrderAddRq>
                        </QBXMLMsgsRq>
                    </QBXML>';

        return $xml;
    }
    /**
     * Receive a response from QuickBooks 
     */
    function _quickbooks_salesorder_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
    {   

    }

    //------------ INVOICE ------------------------------

    function _quickbooks_invoice_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
    {

        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                    <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
                    <QBXML>
                        <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                            <InvoiceAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                                <InvoiceAdd>
                                    <CustomerRef>
                                        <ListID>90001-1263558758</ListID>
                                        <FullName>BhagyaMazire</FullName>
                                    </CustomerRef>
                                    <TxnDate>2010-01-15</TxnDate>
                                    <RefNumber>21011</RefNumber>
                                    <BillAddress>
                                        <Addr1>ConsoliBYTE, LLC</Addr1>
                                        <Addr2>134 Stonemill Road</Addr2>
                                        <Addr3 />
                                        <City>Mansfield</City>
                                        <State>CT</State>
                                        <PostalCode>06268</PostalCode>
                                        <Country>United States</Country>
                                    </BillAddress>
                                    <ShipAddress>
                                        <Addr1>ConsoliBYTE, LLC</Addr1>
                                        <Addr2>Attn: Keith Palmer</Addr2>
                                        <Addr3>56 Cowles Road</Addr3>
                                        <City>Willington</City>
                                        <State>CT</State>
                                        <PostalCode>06279</PostalCode>
                                        <Country>United States</Country>
                                    </ShipAddress>
                                    <TermsRef>
                                        <FullName>Net 30</FullName>
                                    </TermsRef>
                                    <SalesRepRef>
                                        <FullName>KRP</FullName>
                                    </SalesRepRef>
                                    <Memo>Test memo goes here.</Memo>
                                    <InvoiceLineAdd>
                                        <ItemRef>
                                            <FullName>test</FullName>
                                        </ItemRef>
                                        <Desc>Test item description</Desc>
                                        <Quantity>1.00000</Quantity>
                                        <Rate>15.00000</Rate>
                                    </InvoiceLineAdd>
                                </InvoiceAdd>
                            </InvoiceAddRq>
                        </QBXMLMsgsRq>
                    </QBXML>';

        return $xml;
    }
    /**
     * Receive a response from QuickBooks 
     */
    function _quickbooks_invoice_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
    {   

    }

    //-------------- PURCHASE ORDER --------------------------------------
    function _quickbooks_purchaseorder_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
    {

        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                    <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
                    <QBXML>
                        <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                            <PurchaseOrderAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                              <PurchaseOrderAdd>
                                <VendorRef>
                                  <FullName>Test Vendor</FullName>
                                </VendorRef>
                                <TxnDate>2013-01-02</TxnDate>
                                <RefNumber>3434</RefNumber>
                                <PurchaseOrderLineAdd>
                                  <ItemRef>
                                    <FullName>My Item Name</FullName>
                                  </ItemRef>
                                  <Desc>Test description.</Desc>
                                  <Quantity>5</Quantity>
                                  <Rate>29.95</Rate>
                                </PurchaseOrderLineAdd>
                              </PurchaseOrderAdd>
                            </PurchaseOrderAddRq>
                        </QBXMLMsgsRq>
                    </QBXML>';

        return $xml;
    }
    /**
     * Receive a response from QuickBooks 
     */
    function _quickbooks_purchaseorder_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
    {   

    }




    /**
     * Build a request to import sales orders already in QuickBooks into our application
     */
    function _quickbooks_salesorder_import_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
    {
        // Iterator support (break the result set into small chunks)
        $attr_iteratorID = '';
        $attr_iterator = ' iterator="Start" ';
        if (empty($extra['iteratorID']))
        {
            // This is the first request in a new batch
            $last = _quickbooks_get_last_run($user, $action);
            _quickbooks_set_last_run($user, $action);           // Update the last run time to NOW()

            // Set the current run to $last
            _quickbooks_set_current_run($user, $action, $last);
        }
        else
        {
            // This is a continuation of a batch
            $attr_iteratorID = ' iteratorID="' . $extra['iteratorID'] . '" ';
            $attr_iterator = ' iterator="Continue" ';

            $last = _quickbooks_get_current_run($user, $action);
        }

        // Build the request
        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <?qbxml version="' . $version . '"?>
            <QBXML>
                <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                    <SalesOrderQueryRq ' . $attr_iterator . ' ' . $attr_iteratorID . ' requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                        <MaxReturned>' . QB_QUICKBOOKS_MAX_RETURNED . '</MaxReturned>
                        <ModifiedDateRangeFilter>
                            <FromModifiedDate>' . $last . '</FromModifiedDate>
                        </ModifiedDateRangeFilter>
                        <IncludeLineItems>true</IncludeLineItems>
                        <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
                    </SalesOrderQueryRq>    
                </QBXMLMsgsRq>
            </QBXML>';

        return $xml;
    }

    /**
     * Get the last date/time the QuickBooks sync ran
     * 
     * @param string $user      The web connector username 
     * @return string           A date/time in this format: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss"
     */
    function _quickbooks_get_last_run($user, $action)
    {
        $type = null;
        $opts = null;
        return QuickBooks_Utilities::configRead(QB_QUICKBOOKS_DSN, $user, md5(__FILE__), QB_QUICKBOOKS_CONFIG_LAST . '-' . $action, $type, $opts);
    }

    /**
     * Set the last date/time the QuickBooks sync ran to NOW
     * 
     * @param string $user
     * @return boolean
     */
    function _quickbooks_set_last_run($user, $action, $force = null)
    {
        $value = date('Y-m-d') . 'T' . date('H:i:s');

        if ($force)
        {
            $value = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($force)) . 'T' . date('H:i:s', strtotime($force));
        }

        return QuickBooks_Utilities::configWrite(QB_QUICKBOOKS_DSN, $user, md5(__FILE__), QB_QUICKBOOKS_CONFIG_LAST . '-' . $action, $value);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * 
     */
    function _quickbooks_get_current_run($user, $action)
    {
        $type = null;
        $opts = null;
        return QuickBooks_Utilities::configRead(QB_QUICKBOOKS_DSN, $user, md5(__FILE__), QB_QUICKBOOKS_CONFIG_CURR . '-' . $action, $type, $opts);  
    }

    /**
     * 
     * 
     */
    function _quickbooks_set_current_run($user, $action, $force = null)
    {
        $value = date('Y-m-d') . 'T' . date('H:i:s');

        if ($force)
        {
            $value = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($force)) . 'T' . date('H:i:s', strtotime($force));
        }

        return QuickBooks_Utilities::configWrite(QB_QUICKBOOKS_DSN, $user, md5(__FILE__), QB_QUICKBOOKS_CONFIG_CURR . '-' . $action, $value);   
    }
    ?>
```

I am only using `ADD` functionlity and i am getting below error :-
[Error_for_import_but_i_am_using_add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SIdY.png)

Thanks

Comment: @keith-palmer-jr : I think you can answer this question much better.

Comment: @Raghav : We need your help here .

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the quick-start guide linked to on this page:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

See other comments below:

> My basic question is, how i will get sales orders , purchase order etc.

The same way you got customers into QuickBooks. Write a request function. Write a response function. Queue something up.

If you're having trouble, post your code so we can see what you've done so far.

> things which are required in QBDesktop but not available in my site.

None of those things are strictly *required* by QuickBooks. Please talk to your accountant and find out specifically what types of objects you should be pushing to QuickBooks.

> I have also created all tables from here QB Transaction tables ,

This is probably NOT the correct approach. You should have followed the quick-start.

> now point is how to insert data inside these tables.

Why would you want to do that? You already have the data in your WooCommerce database. Why not just use the data you already have?

> so what does that mean Importing from site to QBWC or Importing from QBDesktop to QBWC.

Importing from QuickBooks, to a website. e.g. the opposite of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: you just said , why not use direct woocommerce databases , as there is example for customer it creates temp table `my_customer_table` insert data into it , takes data from it , then puts inside QB which is working for me. So in the same way, I have decided to move on for getting products data also. How can i put all files here whatever i have done?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite following what you're asking... can you rephrase?

Comment: Like you have given example for adding customers from site to quickbooks desktop , which has saving customer data in temporary table called `my_customer_table` , so in the same way do you have examples of Table Structure of adding Products , Estimates , Sales Order etc. Without Schema to save data , we can not proceed further.

Comment: The table structure is completely arbitrary. You don't need to use the example table structure at all. If I were you, I would just use the existing WooCommerce table structure, and change the example queries.

Comment: Let me say what i understood , 1. Get data from woocommerce tables , 2. build XMLs 3. Map handler functions. Now when i try to `QUICKBOOKS_ADD_SALESORDER` , it says `No registered action for SalesOrderImport` , what is the difference between ADD & IMPORT here and is there any way to track error , where the actual error is ?

Comment: Finally i am able to add code sample , i have been trying to add customer and there sales orders from wordpress to quickbook desktop for now with dummy data. Check and let me know what i am missing.

Comment: Add adds things to QuickBooks. Import imports things from QuickBooks. If you want to add things to QuickBooks, use the ADD commands. If you're not trying to IMPORT things from QuickBooks, then make sure you're not queueing anything up that says IMPORT.

Comment: Yes exactly got your point, now my files has only `ADD` things and there functions.. I am just trying to insert sample data not from wordpress database still i am getting errors which i am not able to track from hours.

Comment: What errors are you getting? What do `hours` have anything to do with this? Why does your code still reference `Import` things?

Comment: Please check updated code and also the screenshot the error i am getting.

Comment: Look in the `quickbooks_queue` table, and remove everything from it. You screwed yourself up by screwing with too many examples and need to clear out your queue.

Comment: Ok Thanks ,let me try clearing table `quickbooks_queue`.

Comment: As you said , i have cleared table `quickbooks_queue` , now everytime it says `No data exchange required` but you can see my code i am sending everytime new dummy data.

Comment: Hey , i think now i am able to find the cause of the error. Very much thanks for your help.